# Raw sql execution in Ebean orm

Tags: playframework, orm, ebean

I have been struggling for a while but somehow cannot get it to work. All my resources are depleted and now I am turning to you for an advice.

I have the following SQL which works as expected when executed in Oracle DB directly (if record exist then insert, otherwise update):

```
MERGE INTO license_user dest 
USING (SELECT 'uid' unquid, 3 lid FROM dual) src 
ON (dest.unique_user_id = src.unquid AND dest.license_id = src.lid) 
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET dest.updated = sysdate 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (unique_user_id, license_id) VALUES (src.unquid, src.lid)
```

Project is developed using Ebean ORM and Play 2.5x framework. However I cannot get Ebean to execute this SQL statement.

Most promising solutions tried out, but do not work:

- Code is executed and also 1 row is affected according to returned int, but changes are not reflected to DB. (if I put normal insert into this code, it works and is reflected in DB)

  ```
  SqlUpdate query = Ebean.createSqlUpdate(sql);
  int rowsAffected = query.execute();
  ```
- I put SQL into RawSql object, but I dont know how to execute it. At the end I am not doing anything like: findUnique or findList. I am just trying to execute.

  ```
  RawSql raw = RawSqlBuilder.unparsed(sql);
  Ebean.find(LicenseUser.class).setRawSql(raw).???
  ```

Any help or pointing me to the right direction would be greatly appreciated.